# To Passw value to Crystal Report Header from text Box

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i create a crystal report and works fine but my problem is to pass textbox value to crystal report header

To Generate report i use two date time picker to get the report between two date my problem is to print out this two date on crystal report header

like 
 report From 'txtfrom.text'  To 'txtto.text'

here are my code

```
protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=YCC-DB-2K8;Initial Catalog=yccwebportal;User ID=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd");
    string sql = "select * from View_EQtype where Purchase_date between '"+ txtfrom.Text + "'AND'" + txtto.Text+"'";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(ds, "View_EQtype");
    cnn.Open();
    ReportDocument myReportDocument;
    myReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
    myReportDocument.Load("C:/inetpub/wwwroot/yenwebportal/EQTypeReport.rpt");
    myReportDocument.SetDataSource(ds);
    myReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "p@ssw0rd");
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReportDocument;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayToolbar = true;
    CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Report Parameters 
Make two parameters Names (FromDate),(ToDate)
And Send Paramter Values By using

```
//paramter from
    ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value ="";//Desire Date From
            crParameterFieldDefinitions = EQTypeReport.rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["FromDate"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
            crParameterValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);
            //paramter DateTo
            ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions2;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition2;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues2 = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue2 = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
            crParameterDiscreteValue2.Value = ""; //Desire Date To
            crParameterFieldDefinitions2 = EQTypeReport.rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition2 = crParameterFieldDefinitions2["ToDate"];
            crParameterValues2 = crParameterFieldDefinition2.CurrentValues;
            crParameterValues2.Clear();
            crParameterValues2.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue2);
            crParameterFieldDefinition2.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues2);
```

then Use Paramters in Report

Answer (score 0):

Create two parameter fields in your report and set the date like :

```
        myReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@FromDate", DateToString(RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate));

        myReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@ToDate", DateToString(RadDatePicker2.SelectedDate));
```

or like this:
your datasource as datatable

```
myReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
myReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath(RPTName));
DT.Columns.Add("From_Date");
DT.Columns.Add("To_Date");
DT.Rows(0).Item("From_Date") = DateToString(RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate);
DT.Rows(0).Item("To_Date") = DateToString(RadDatePicker2.SelectedDate);
myReportDocument.SetDataSource(DT);
```

they will appear in the field explorer as filed objects

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you want to pass the values from code to the text object of Crystal Report. Lets say you have txtFromDate and txtToDate text object in the your report:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject txtFromDate = mainReport.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtFromDate "] as TextObject;
txtFromDate .Text = DateTimePickerFrom.SelectedValue.ToString();

CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject txtToDate = mainReport.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["txtToDate "] as TextObject;
txtToDate.Text = DateTimePickerTo.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

So, you need to make an instance of the text objects. If you don't want that, I used in my report the same thing in the Header by drag and drop the parameters like this:

[image]

I hope this helped you.